# Update row values in a dataframe based on another row's values?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with two columns: `a` and `b`

df

```
         a         b
0       john      123
1       john
2       mark     
3       mark      456
4       marcus    789
```

I want to update values of `b` column based on `a` column.

```
         a         b
0       john      123
1       john      123
2       mark      456
3       mark      456
4       marcus    789
```

If `john` has value `123` in `b`. Remaining `john` also must have same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your dataframe is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['john', 'john', 'mark', 'mark', 'marcus'], 'b': [123, '', '', 456, 789]})
```

You can [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the dataframe on column `a` and then apply `transform` on the column `b` of the grouped dataframe returning the first non empty value in the grouped column `b`.

Use:

```
df['b'] = (
    df.groupby('a')['b']
    .transform(lambda s: s[s.ne('')].iloc[0] if s.ne('').any() else s)
)
```

Result:

```
# print(df)

        a    b
0    john  123
1    john  123
2    mark  456
3    mark  456
4  marcus  789
```

Comment: Thanks. But if last row's 'b' value Is empty. `marcus` is ` `. Then what's should be the case

Comment: @Zanthoxylumpiperitum Well in that case i have to modify the answer.

Comment: @Zanthoxylumpiperitum What value do you expect in column `b` in such case?

Comment: Same as the original value

Comment: @Zanthoxylumpiperitum Check the edited answer. Now this should work in such case.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0," ", 2, 3, 4],
                   'B': [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                   'C': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})

df1=df.replace({'A':" "},3)
```

Hope this helps, In your case it would be like

```
df1=df.replace({'b':" "},123)
```